# Measuring accuracy in SparkR

Tags: sparkr

I am building a simple Random forest model on iris data in spark, I was hoping for some method of accuracy measure.

I thought of a simple column matching option too, however this did not work

**Code:**

```
library("SparkR")

sc = sparkR.session("local[*]")

iris_data <- as.DataFrame(iris)

train <- sample(iris_data, withReplacement=FALSE, fraction=0.5, seed=42)
test <- except(iris_data, train)


model_rf <- spark.randomForest(train, Species ~., "classification", numTrees = 10)

summary(model_rf)
```

**Problem:**

```
predictions <- predict(model_rf, test)

total_rows <- NROW(test)

predictions$correct <- (test$Species == test$prediction)

accuracy <- correct/total_rows

print(accuracy)
```

**Error:**

```
Error in column(callJMethod(x@sdf, "col", c)) :
```

P.S: 
Using data bricks to run spark, don't mind running locally either

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I did it,

```
total_rows <- NROW(test)

predictions$result  <- ifelse((predictions$Species == predictions$prediction), 
                               "TRUE", "FALSE")

correct <- NROW(predictions[predictions$result == "TRUE",])

accuracy <- correct/total_rows

cat(accuracy, "%")
```